# What is rapid signal attenuation?

Tags: wireless, signal-processing, attenuation

Attenuation describes the weakening of the signal as it travels from the transmitter to the receiver. However, [this textbook](https://web.stanford.edu/~dntse/Chapters_PDF/Fundamentals_Wireless_Communication_chapter2.pdf) describes a concept called "rapid signal attenuation" as a way to allow frequencies to to be reused in closer distances.

How does rapid signal attenuation help reuse frequencies? What does it do to help us reuse frequencies without interference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misinterpreting that sentence.

There's no new concept introduced in

> On the
>   other hand, rapid signal attenuation with distance is also helpful; it reduces the
>   interference between adjacent cells.

It's simply that if your signal quickly loses power over distance, someone else can use that same part of the spectrum e.g. for their own calls.

Given technical users per cell limitations, the operator of the cellular network needs *fewer* spectrum licenses when their signals don't reach far.

Comment: So it's saying that even though signals are often lost over short distances; it's actually a good thing because it allows us to reuse frequencies in shorter distances.

Comment: You need that loss to be "reliable", not "often", but yeah. Exactly. It's a "on the other hand" sentence that gives you the positive effect this might have. It really depends on what you're doing!

Comment: This is why there is so much interest in using high frequencies for indoor communications. 2.4 GHz goes through walls, 5 GHz goes through doors, 60 GHz has trouble going through a decent amount of paper - and as a result you can have nodes in every room and far less crowding in your signal bands.